# How do I correctly make two API calls prior to rendering my page in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

When trying to asynchronously make two API calls, my `useState()` for the second API call is not updating on the page until the page re-renders. I am trying to check if the page is loading before rendering with `isLoading`.

I've tried a few different promise/asynchronous approaches - even creating my own unoptimized version of a promise with `setTimeout()`

`isLoading`

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
```

`Api Calls`

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    (async () => {
      await axios.get(`http://localhost:4242/player/${id}`).then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
        setPlayer({ ...data });
      });
      await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:4242/team/${player.team_ID}`)
        .then((res) => {
          const data = res.data;
          setTeam({ ...data });
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    })();
  }, []);
```

`Render`

```
<>
  <Navbar/>
  {isLoading && <Spinner/>}
  {player && team && <Player/>}
  <LoginWidget/>
  <Footer/>
</>
```

Edit: I was able to fix this issue by using response data from the first API call instead of trying to access the `useState()` variable. I also switched this to a trycatch.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const { data: playerRes } = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:4242/player/${id}`
        );
        setPlayer({ ...playerRes });
        const { data: teamRes } = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:4242/team/${playerRes.team_ID}`
        );
        setTeam({ ...teamRes });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, it is tricky to say why this is happening. Maybe it's because `isLoading` is set to `false` only after the second API call completes, which might not sync well with the initial render (or re-renders) of the React component.

Either way, as the two API calls don't depend on each other, it would be better to use `Promise.all` to fire them off at the same time and then proceed only when both have completed.

This is how I would do it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  Promise.all([
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4242/player/${id}`),
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4242/team/${player.team_ID}`)
  ])
  .then(([playerRes, teamRes]) => {
    setPlayer({ ...playerRes.data });
    setTeam({ ...teamRes.data });
    setIsLoading(false);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle errors
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will use `Promise.all()` in the future for API calls that I don't need to work with each other. For this though, I needed to access the `team_ID` value from my player API call.

I was able to fix it by using response data for the second call, I'm assuming my issue is that I was trying to access the data before it was updated because of the useEffect. But when rendering everything with the data from the response it works as intended. 

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it seems likely that the original problem stemmed from trying to use `player.team_ID` before it was updated. By directly using the value returned from the the first API call, this ensures that the correct ID is used for the second one. Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using await, you can also try the following:

useEffect(() => {

```
(async () => {
     setIsLoading(true);

     const resp1 = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4242/player/${id}`);
     const data1 = resp1.data;

     const resp2 = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4242/team/${player.team_ID}`);
     const data2 = resp2.data;

     if (data1 && data2) {
          setPlayer({ ...data1 });
          setTeam({ ...data2 });
          setIsLoading(false);
     }

})();
```

}, []);